# Executing python script on mongodb insert

Tags: python, mongodb, raspberry-pi

I have a mongodb on my raspberry pi. Also, I have a java application that inserts documents into the database.
I need to automatically call a python script every time the database changes (something gets inserted, etc.) on the raspberry pi.
How can I do this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running MongoDB 3.6 or later, you can take advantage of [database triggers](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/database-triggers/) and [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) to do this.